# Manejo de Cadenas de texto en C++

Tags: c++

Para [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

1. ¿Cómo agrego un "nueva línea" o <kbd>enter</kbd> + el valor de una variable numérica a una cadena de texto?
2. ¿Cómo puedo obtener ese valor numérico de la última línea de una cadena de texto?

Comment: `int a = 5; std::string s = "Nueva linea: \n Valor de a: " + std::to_string(a); //¿No funciona?` Funciona en C++11+

Answer (score 17):

### ¿Cómo agrego un "nueva línea" o <kbd>enter</kbd>?

La nueva línea es un tipo de caracter conocido como "caracter no imprimible" ya que afecta a cómo se muestra el texto pero no tiene representación gráfica.

La [tabla de caracteres ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) contiene el listado de caracteres imprimibles y no imprimibles:

> ASCII fue publicado como estándar por primera vez en 1967 y fue actualizado por última vez en 1986. **En la actualidad define códigos para 32 caracteres no imprimibles**, de los cuales **la mayoría son [caracteres de control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car%C3%A1cter_de_control)** que tienen efecto sobre cómo se procesa el texto, más otros 95 caracteres imprimibles que les siguen en la numeración (empezando por el carácter espacio).

La mayoría de veces no es posible escribir caracteres no imprimibles en el código, no sólo por no tener representación gráfica si no porque pueden provocar problemas de compilación; el ejemplo más claro es el de la nueva línea:

```
std::string texto = "La lluvia en Sevilla
es una maravilla.";
```

El ejemplo anterior provoca error porque el compilador considera ambas líneas como instrucciones separadas porque la nueva línea está en medio del texto. Para evitar este problema la mayoría de lenguajes de programación usan [secuencias de escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

#### Secuencias de escape.

Una secuencia de escape se suele escribir con una barra descendente (`\`) seguida de un código predeterminado para dicho carácter.

Algunas de las secuencias de escape aceptadas en C++ [son las siguientes](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape):

- `\'` Comilla simple.
- `\"` Comillas dobles.
- `\?` Símbolo de interrogación.
- `\\` Barra descendente.
- `\a` [Beep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beep_(sound)).
- `\b` [Retroceso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroceso_(tecla)).
- `\f` [Form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed)
- `\n` Nueva de línea.
- `\r` [Retorno de carro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retorno_de_carro).
- `\t` Tabulación.
- `\v` Tabulación vertical.

Vemos que la nueva línea tiene la secuencia de escape `\n`, que en C++ se usaría de la siguiente manera:

```
std::cout << "La lluvia en Sevilla\nes una maravilla.";
//                                ^^
```

Y el texto se mostraría de la siguiente manera:

> ```
> La lluvia en Sevilla
> es una maravilla.
> ```

#### Literal de texto en crudo (C++11 o superior).

En C++ a partir del estándar de 2011 es posible usar una alternativa a las secuencias de escape para incluir algunos caracteres no imprimibles en una cadena de texto, la alternativa es usar literales de texto en crudo ([Raw string literals](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings)).

Un literal de texto en crudo se abre con la secuencia `R"(` y se cierra con la secuencia `)"`<sup>1</sup> así pues este texto:

```
std::cout << R"(La lluvia en Sevilla
es una maravilla.)";
```

Se muestra correctamente:

> ```
> La lluvia en Sevilla
> es una maravilla.
> ```

Hay que tener en cuenta que el literal de texto en crudo no sirve para todos los caracteres de control, por ejemplo: no hay manera de escribir en el código el caracter Beep. También debe mencionarse que en un literal de texto normal la secuencia `"\n"` produce una nueva línea mientras que en un literal de texto en crudo la secuencia `"\n"` produce el caracter de diagonal descendente `\` y la letra ene `n`.

### El valor de una variable numérica a una cadena de texto.

Para mostrar valores de variables, puedes usar la cabecera [`<iostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) de la que el objeto `std::cout` forma parte.

La cabecera `<iostream>` se encarga de la comunicación del usuario con la consola y puedes usarla de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "La lluvia en Sevilla\nes una maravilla.";
    float PI = 3.14;
    int entero = 10;
    short corto = 9;
    unsigned long long fabada = 0xfabada;

    std::cout << "Pi no es tres: " << PI      << '\n'
              << "El entero es: "  << entero  << '\n'
              << "El corto es: "   << corto   << '\n'
              << "El valor de la fabada es: " << fabada;

    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, para mostrar una variable, la puedes *inyectar* usando el operador `<<`. En el ejemplo anterior, se inyecta texto y variables en el objeto `std::cout` que es conocido como "**c**onsole **out**put", si quieres añadir la variable en una cadena de texto, necesitaras las cabeceras [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) y [`<sstream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

- La cabecera `<string>` te permite manejar y almacenar cadenas de texto.
- La cabecera `<sstream>` te permite dar formato texto a datos.

Puedes usarlas así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string cadena("Este es el texto inicial\n");
    std::stringstream s;
    s << cadena << "añadimos la fabada " << fabada << "\n\tEsto esta tabulado!";
    std::cout << s.str();

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior debería mostrar el siguiente texto:

> ```
>  Este es el texto inicial
>  añadimos la fabada 16431834
>          Esto esta tabulado!
> ```

Igual que en el caso anterior, hemos usado el operador `<<` para *inyectar* en el objeto `s` varios datos, el objeto `s` (de tipo `std::stringstream`) los ha transformado en texto. Cuando hemos necesitado recuperar esos datos, nos ha bastado con llamar a la funcón `str()` del objeto `s`.

Puedes ver todo el ejemplo en [[Wandbox]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eKNnxYWwboXrT6Tx), que es un compilador de C++ online con el que podrás experimentar.

### ¿Cómo puedo obtener ese valor numérico de la última línea de una cadena de texto?

#### Pasar de texto a número.

C++ tiene dos librerías que pueden hacerse cargo de pasar texto a número, la cabecera [`<cstdlib>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) es una adaptación a C++ de una librería de C y contiene la función [`std::atoi`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) de la cabecera [`<cstdlib>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib):

```
std::string cuarenta_y_dos("42");
int numero = std::atoi("42") + std::atoi(cuarenta_y_dos.c_str());
```

La función `std::atoi` espera recibir un puntero a una cadena de caracteres, por eso debe llamarse el método `c_str` de `std::string`.

Pero yo prefiero la opción de usar un [stream de texto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::stringstream stream("42");
int numero = 0;
stream >> numero; // aqui inyectamos el valor 42 a la variable numero
```

#### Leer la última línea de un texto.

Entiendo que la última línea es aquel texto que va desde el último salto de línea y el final del texto, siendo así puedes obtener esa sub-cadena haciendo una búsqueda inversa (del final al principio) del último caracter de nueva línea, usando las cabeceras [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) e [`<iterator>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator):

```
char texto1[] = "Hexakosioihexekontahexafobia\n666";
std::string texto2 = "Triscaidecafobia\n13";

auto ultimo1 = std::find(std::rbegin(texto1), std::rend(texto1), '\n');
auto ultimo2 = std::find(std::rbegin(texto2), std::rend(texto2), '\n');
```

En el ejemplo anterior hemos usado [iteradores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterador_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) inversos (que se desplazan de final a principio) para hacer una búsqueda sobre textos, tras las llamadas a [la función de búsqueda](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) las variables `ultimo1` y `ultimo2` contendrán la posición en que se encuentra el caracter de nueva línea, de esa posición hacia atrás (porque el iterador es inverso) tendremos el número:

```
char texto1[] = "Hexakosioihexekontahexafobia\n666";
std::string texto2 = "Triscaidecafobia\n13";

auto r1 = std::find(std::rbegin(texto1), std::rend(texto1), '\n');
auto r2 = std::find(std::rbegin(texto2), std::rend(texto2), '\n');

std::cout << '"' << &*(r1 - 1) << '"' << '\n'; // Imprime "666"
std::cout << '"' << &*(r2 - 1) << '"' << '\n'; // Imprime "13"
```

.

---

<sup>1</sup>Otras secuencias de apertura/cierre son posibles, siempre y cuando la apertura y el cierre coincidan, por ejemplo: `R"***(Literal de texto en crudo)***"` es igualmente válido.

Comment: Un pequeño comentario: a partir del estándar del 2011, existe dentro de la librería `<string>` la función `stoi`, la cual sirve para lo mismo que `atoi`, con la ventaja de que ya no es necesario utilizar el método `c_str`.

Answer (score 1):

Va un ejemplo, con algún comentario en el código.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


/* 1) ¿Cómo agrego un "nueva línea" o enter +
   el valor de una variable numérica a una
   cadena de texto?
*/
template<typename T>
std::string agregarNum(const std::string& s, T num)
{
    std::string str{s};
    str += "\n" + std::to_string(num);
    return str;
}

/* 2) ¿Cómo puedo obtener ese valor numérico
      de la última línea de una cadena de texto?
*/
template<typename T>
T obtenerUltimoNum(const std::string& str)
{
    size_t pos = str.find_last_of("\n");
    if(pos != str.npos) {
        std::string sub = str.substr(pos+1);
        std::stringstream ss(sub);
        T num;
        ss >> num;
        return num;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("error: no hay un número al final de la cadena.");
    // o return T{}; al estilo de atoi()
    // y si esperás al C++17 std::optional.
}

int main()
{
    std::string cadena {"Hola mundo"};

    cadena = agregarNum(cadena, 4.5);

    std::cout << "cadena: " << cadena << '\n';

    double num = obtenerUltimoNum<double>(cadena);

    std::cout << "num: " << num << '\n';

}
```